# Redis pub/sub authentication

Tags: android, redis

I need to stream live data from my server (hopefully through Redis) to Android clients. I went ahead and developed a server that supported Redis pub/sub model, which was all fine an dandy, until I realized that connecting untrusted clients to Redis is a big "no-no" according to this documentation https://redis.io/topics/security. (my fault for not doing proper research ahead of development)

As Redis barely has a sense of security to it I am struggling with figuring out how to connect untrusted clients to my server. I understand there are other message brokers - like RabbitMQ - which indeed has better support for authentication and authorization. This will be my fallback, but I do wonder if there is a way to connect untrusted client to my Redis server in a secure fashion? Possibly by proxying Redis somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seemingly it cannot be done. Redis is really just not made to be used by untrusted clients. Making a simple proxy was not an option either because even though I would be able to authenticate users I would not be able to apply any access control. Resulting in end-clients being able to publish messages to my server etc...

I ended up building a SignalR WebSocket server that clients must connect to. This server will subscribe to the correct channels on Redis and act as a layer of security.